# Merge vertices at individual centers

Tags: modeling

I would like to clean up some geometry, I need to get rid of dozens of small triangles. I am able to select many of them by using "Select similar: Area", but I can not clean them up all at once. Instead, I have to go and select them one by one, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select "Merge: At Center" for each one of them.

Is there a way to merge them all at once, at their individual centers? I tried switching pivot point to "individual origins" but it doesn't change anything.

[image: tiny triangles]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Edge collapse

As stated by the [Blender reference manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#collapse):

> This takes a selection of edges and for each edge, merges its two vertices together

Despite the description look quite simple, the algorithm is capable of iterating the process upon several selection clusters.

The operator can be triggered by the option in the "deleting menu" that pop up after pressing <kbd>X</kbd> key as in the image sequence below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Switch pivot point to *Individual Origins* with all regions selected
2. Scale to zero (press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select *Remove Doubles*

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'd want to merge edges individually and I wasn't able to, this was my workarround.

In this image below, you can see that I have separated edges that came from mirror modififer, I tried to solve this using clipping, but it didnt work.

[image: edge merging, first image]

To solve:
Edit Mode -> Remove Doubles -> Choose a value that fits in ur case, mine was 0.00910m

[image: edge merging, second image]

In case u dont have noticed, on the image says the default value of the `Remove Doubles` tool wich is 0.00001m. Another thing is pressing shift and dragging the mouse left and right to softly change the values.